# How to apply .pkl (ML Model) to entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle

I have a model in pickle form (model1.pkl),And I need to predict on new excel file that has been given to me,Currently I am using pandas to loop over each row and get the answer

```
df=pd.read_excel("data.xlsx") 
model1 = pickle.load(open('model1.pkl', 'rb'))
appts=(list(df['apptid'].unique()))

for i in appts:
    fdf = df[df['apptid'] == i]
    fdf.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    fdf.reset_index(inplace=True)
    hdf = fdf
    fdf = fdf.iloc[:1]
    ans = model1.predict(
        [[fdf['a'][0], fdf['b'][0], fdf['c'][0],
          fdf['d'][0], fdf['e'][0], fdf['f'][0], fdf['g'][0]]])
    fdf['ans'] = int(round(ans[0]))
    print("anssss", ans[0])
```

Is there any other way where i need not loop and could directly predict for all the rows available in excel??